# Swift compiler vs Objective-C compiler

Tags: objective-c, swift, compiler-optimization

I'm preparing a research about the performance of Swift so these are my questions: can we make optimisations while compiling Objective-C project? and if Swift and Objective-C have the same compiler, why we're talking only about optimisation of Swift compiler?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Objective C compiler is Clang. Swift uses the "Swift compiler". While they both leverage LLVM to produce the final machine code, they are in fact completely separate compilers.

Answer (score 10):

There are different pipelines for Swift and ObjC but both of them are backed by LLVM.

Objective-C uses the Clang compiler to compile the code. So for good old ObjC code, the pipeline looks like this:

[image]

You can see that the first conversion Clang makes over your code is the creation of AST’ (Abstract Syntax Tree) - the representation where all the functions, operators, variables, declarations.. are nodes of the huge semantic tree.
LLVM IR is being passed from Clang to LLVM Core where the code is optimized (if applicable) and converted to target-specific machine code. As a result, we have a bunch of object files (*.o) which are linked together later on and merged into an executable or dynamic library. The output of this last stage is typically called an “a.out”, “.dylib” or “.so” file.

As you could already see LLVM Core is the place where the code is optimized, and Intermediate Representation is specifically the source of these optimizations.

Swift uses the Swift-C to compile the code. In terms of code optimization, some features are being changed and new features appear almost every year. (What I’m writing here about is valid for Swift 4.2 and XCode 10)

Let’s take a look at the compilation pipeline for Swift:

[image]

You can see lots of similarities with the one for ObjC: not only the same backend but also the frontend essentially works similarly. Lexical analysis, tokenization (separating some lexical items from the raw string), building AST, type checking. The main difference is the presence of SIL (Swift Intermediate Language) - another intermediate code representation between AST and LLVM IR.

The Swift development team took Clang as an example for a frontend, tried to use all Clang’s advantages and compensate for some flaws. One of those flaws was an inability to implement some high-level analysis, reliable diagnostics, and optimizations for which neither ATS nor LLVM IR was a proper material. So SIL was the solution to this problem.

Additional references:
Difference:

https://dmtopolog.com/code-optimization-for-swift-and-objective-c/

Clang:

https://clang.llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/clang.html#description
https://clang.llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/clang.html#code-generation-options

LLVM:

Video: A Brief Introduction to LLVM
Video: D. Dunbar “A New Architecture for Building Software”

LLVM optimization:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/Performance/Performance.html (Compiler-Level Optimizations section)
https://pewpewthespells.com/blog/buildsettings.html#gcc_optimization_level (XCode Build Settings Reference)

Swift compiler:

https://modocache.io/reading-and-understanding-the-swift-driver-source-code

Swift optimizations:

https://swift.org/blog/osize/
https://swift.org/blog/whole-module-optimizations/

SIL:

Documentation
Video: Joseph Groff & Chris Lattner Swift’s High-Level IR